# Class member function pointer

Tags: c++, arduino, function-pointers

I'm trying to use a class function (interrupt service routine),

```
void (ClassName::*fp)(void)=ClassName::FunctionName;
```

and attaching it to an Arduino interrupt pin using the function with the following type inputs but that doesn't work.

```
void attachInterrupt(int, void (*)(void),int);
```

How can I make this happen? The interrupt service routine (ISR) needs to access privat object data, so I can't make a function outside of the class.

My compiler error:

```
ClassName.cpp : : In constructor 'ClassName::ClassName()':
ClassName.cpp : *)()'
ClassName.cpp : *)()' to 'void (*)()' for argument '2' to 'void attachInterrupt(uint8_t, void (*)(), int)'
```

Note: I am looking for a solution inside the class and will accept the answer that shows me a solution or shows me it's not possible.

Comment: Are you getting an error. What error is it?

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio 2012 compiler. I'll put the compiler error into my question.

Comment: sorry, wrong compiler error at first, now its right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the function is not `static`, you cannot pass it in input to a function that accepts a non-member function pointer.

Consider that a non-`static` member function has an implicit pointer to `ClassName` as its first parameter, which points to the object on which the member function is being invoked.

```
struct X
{
    static void foo() { } // Does not have an implicit "this" pointer argument
    void bar() { } // Has an implicit "this" pointer argument
};

int main()
{
    void (*f)() = &X::foo; // OK: foo is static
    void (*g)() = &X::bar; // ERROR! bar is non-static
}
```

Here, not even `std::bind()` will work, because the result is not convertible to a function pointer. Lambdas are convertible to function pointers, but only if they are non-capturing (and a lambda here would need to capture the object to invoke the member function on).

Therefore, the only (ugly) workaround is to have a global adapter function which invokes the member function on an object which is available through a global pointer variable. The global pointer variable is set prior to calling the function:

```
struct X
{
    void bar() { }
};

void function_taking_a_function_pointer(void (*f)())
{
    // Do something...
    f();
}

X* pX = nullptr;
void bar_adapter()
{
    pX->bar();
}

int main()
{
    X x; // Some object I want to invoke the member function bar() on...

    pX = &x; // Set the global pointer and invoke the function...
    function_taking_a_function_pointer(bar_adapter);
}
```

If you want, you can make this slightly more flexible by turning `bar_adapter` into a function *template*, and passing the pointer-to-member-function as a template argument:

```
template<typename T, void (T::*mf)()>
void adapter()
{
    (pX->*mf)();
}
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "X::foo()" << std::endl; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "X::bar()" << std::endl; }
};

void function_taking_a_function_pointer(void (*f)())
{
    // Do something...
    f();
}

X* pX = nullptr;

template<typename T, void (T::*mf)()>
void adapter()
{
    (pX->*mf)();
}

int main()
{
    X x; // Some object I want to invoke the member function bar() on...

    pX = &x; // Set the global pointer and invoke the function(s)...

    function_taking_a_function_pointer(adapter<X, &X::foo>);
    function_taking_a_function_pointer(adapter<X, &X::bar>);
}
```

Finally, here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/41HfPq%2438).

Answer (score 2):

Each class member function has an implicit first parameter that is the `this` pointer, so your method in fact is not with void paramter list - it takes one parameter-- the instance it is invoked on.

Comment: Ok thanks this makes sense but doesn't solve my problem. Is the only thing I can do to make the object data public and make a ISR outside of the object? or is there a work around?

Comment: @FlyingSwissman: I am proposing a workaround in my answer. Unfortunately, there is not much that can be done when a function accepts a raw function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boost::function<>` or `boost::bind<>` to point to a class member function:

```
# include <boost/function.hpp>
# include <boost/bind.hpp>
class FunctionClass {
    private:
       double a_;
    public:
       FunctionClass (const double & a): a_(a ){}
       double multWithA (const double & x) const { return a_*x;}
       double operator ()(const double & x) const { return a_*x;}
};

FunctionClass myClass (2.0);
double x = 12.0;
boost :: function <double (FunctionClass *, double)> funcPtr , funcPtr1;
funcPtr =& FunctionClass :: multWithA;
funcPtr1 =& FunctionClass :: operator ();

std :: cout << myClass . multWithA (x) << std :: endl;
std :: cout << funcPtr (& myClass ,x) << std :: endl;
std :: cout << funcPtr1 (& myClass ,x) << std :: endl;

// Bind the function with the class instance
boost :: function <double (double)> funcPtrNew ;
funcPtrNew = boost :: bind (funcPtr ,& myClass ,_1);
std :: cout << funcPtrNew (x) << std :: endl;
```

Comment: He can't, he has to pass a `void (*)(void)` function pointer. (I'm not a big fan of the arduino library.)

Comment: Because he has to call [void attachInterrupt(int, void (*)(void),int)](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AttachInterrupt).