# Using a function pointer from one class in a function of another class

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have looked at the following threads, but they do not seem to help resolve the issue:

[Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function) - this thread does not help because the access is made within main and not another class

[one class should invoke method of another class using a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582223/one-class-should-invoke-method-of-another-class-using-a-function-pointer) - I could not follow the accepted answer as it is not clear to me how to use `<functional>` header.

I have a **U**seful **F**unction class, `UF`, in which I declare and define all common utility functions for my program. One of these functions is

```
int UF::compar_dbl_asc(const void *a, const void *b)//comparator for sorting 
{                                                   //array of double in ascending order
    int aa = *((int *)a), bb = *((int *)b);
    if (base_arr_dbl[aa] < base_arr_dbl[bb])
        return -1;
    if (base_arr_dbl[aa] == base_arr_dbl[bb])
        return 0;
    if (base_arr_dbl[aa] > base_arr_dbl[bb])
        return 1;
}
```

This is a comparator function that I intend to use within `qsort()` for sorting doubles in ascending order.

Within `UF` class definition, I also have `double* base_arr_dbl;` as a declaration. This is the array of values (doubles) that qsort will use.

Now, in a different class of mine named `SEP`, I have a function, `fn1` wherein I would like to have `base_arr_dbl` point to a local (to `fn1`) double array and I would like to invoke `qsort` using the comparator function in `UF`. To be very specific although this is possibly not needed, I do not sort the actual values' array, but will sort an array of indices `sortedindices[]`, such that `sortedindices[0]` will hold the index of the smallest entry in `base_arr_dbl[]` array. That is, the sorted order is `base_arr_dbl[sortedindices[0]], base_arr_dbl[sortedindices[1]]`, etc.

So, I do this:

```
void SEP::fn1(UF *uf) {

    double ratio[100];
    //populate ratio's entries
    //Now, sort ratio's entries.
    uf->set_base_arr_dbl(ratio); //This function is defined as
   //void UF::set_base_arr_dbl(double *ptr) { base_arr_dbl = ptr; }
    qsort(sortedindices, 100, sizeof(double), uf->compar_dbl_asc);

}
```

However, the line `qsort(sortedindices, 100, sizeof(double), uf->compar_dbl_asc);` throws the following compile time error:

`error C3867: 'USEFUL_FUNCTIONS::compar_dbl_asc': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

I tried having `&uf->compar_dbl_asc` but that gives the error:

`error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`

Any way to help resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: *"I have a Useful Function class, UF, in which I declare and define all common utility functions for my program"* That sounds like such a horrible design

Comment: Why not have a namespace instead? Do your utility functions require state?

Comment: And otherwise, can't these utility functions be `static` within the class so that you wouldn't require an instance?

Comment: @AndyG I am not knowledgeable about what it means for functions to require states. Could you elaborate? Also, would that help resolve this function pointer issue?

Comment: @Tryer: I mean member variables. Does `UF` have member variables, and if so, why? It seems like you have a design problem that you should solve first. We could help you write code that would theoretically work in this design, but it would encourage bad design principles.

Comment: @CoryKramer could you indicate whether that would lead to performance related issues? Also, what are good ways to have commonly used utility functions defined and declared?

Comment: The syntax for pointer to member function is not `&uf->compar_dbl_asc` but `&class_name::compar_dbl_asc`. However, that will never work for the C function `qsort` which knows absolutely nothing about member functions.

Comment: @Tryer: The most common way is to write a namespace with the functions. You could name it `utility`. `&utility::compar_dbl_asc` would look better than what you have

Comment: @AndyG interestingly, it was to have this `qsort` work that I had to introduce my very first variable, `double* base_arr_dbl;` within UF class. Otherwise, there are no variables, only public member functions. Let me look into namespaces and see if that would help resolve the issue.

Comment: @BoPersson so what you are saying is that with this current design, there is no way to get this done. Namespace is the only way?

Comment: You can never get a C function to directly call a C++ member function. Indirection through a non-member helper function might work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler clearly tells in the error messages, neither `uf->compar_dbl_asc` nor `&(uf->compar_dbl_asc)` is appropriate for use as an argument to `qsort`.

You can use `compar_dbl_asc` as an argument to `qsort` using one of the following approaches.

1. Make `compar_dbl_asc` a `static` member function of the class.
2. Better yet, create a `namespace` for your app and define `compar_dbl_asc` in the `namespace`. `UF` could be that `namespace` unless it must be a class for some other reasons.

Another choice would be forego use of `qsort` in favor of `std::sort`. The latter gives you more options. You can use a functor or a lambda function when you use `std::sort`, which will allow you to use `UF::compar_dbl_asc`.

```
std::sort(sortedindices, sortedindices+100,
          [=uf](int a, int b) { return uf->compar_dbl_asc(a, b); });
```

One thing to note is that if you choose the last approach, the signature of `UF::compar_dbl_asc` can be changed to a more user friendly variation.

```
bool UF::compar_dbl_asc(int a, int b)
   return (base_arr_dbl[a] < base_arr_dbl[b]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me look into namespaces. I am guessing, like classes, namespaces would also be declared in the main header file?

Comment: @R Sahu I think I will choose option 2, of namespace. Could you indicate what the syntax of `qsort(sortedindices, 100, sizeof(double), uf->compar_dbl_asc);` would have to be changed to? I will declare `UF` as the name of the namespace. I don't need to have it as a class.

Comment: @Tryer,  use `UF::compar_dbl_asc`.