# Have I to create a Object to use a class method in c++?

Tags: c++, class, c++builder

I'm trying to create a simple Form in C++Builder, and I'm trying to create an `adding()` method in a class, but if I can, I don't want to create an object just to use a method that doesn't save any values.

This is the source of the class file:

```
class Op{
public:
    double adding(double x, double y);
};

double Op::adding(double x, double y){
    return x + y;
}
```

And this is the action that calls the button:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    double value1 = text1->Text.ToDouble();
    double value2 = text2->Text.ToDouble();
    double result = Op.adding(value1, value2);
}
```

But I get a compile error:

> improper use of typedef 'Op'

If I have to create the object like `Op operations;`, please tell me how.

Comment: Make your function `static`, and call it like `Op::adding();`

Comment: Try `Op{}.adding(value1, value2);`

Comment: Note that the `Op{}` syntax is introduced in C++11, which requires C++Builder's [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang), and not its [Classic compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32).

Comment: If the function has nothing to do with the class, why does it have to be a member?

Comment: Because i need a file to save all of my methods, i cannot put all of my Utilities in the same file as "main". But maybe i should consider using a namespace instead of class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what you are attempting, declare `adding()` as `static`:

```
class Op{
public:
    static double adding(double x, double y);
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
double result = Op::adding(value1, value2);
```

If you don't declare it as `static`, you do indeed need to create an object first, eg:

```
Op operation;
double result = operation.adding(value1, value2);
```

Or:

```
double result = Op().adding(value1, value2);
```

Or, if using one of C++Builder's [Clang-based compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang):

```
double result = Op{}.adding(value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you are only defining functions in a class and no data, it is better to consider using namespaces instead of classes. Please see this thread: [Using a function pointer from one class in a function of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412593/using-a-function-pointer-from-one-class-in-a-function-of-another-class)

In this case you may consider the following design:

```
namespace Op{//this will go into a header file
    double adding(double x, double y){
        return x + y;
    }
    //define other functions as required
};

//usage in .cpp implementation file
//include the header file containing the namespace 
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    double value1 = text1->Text.ToDouble();
    double value2 = text2->Text.ToDouble();
    double result = Op::adding(value1, value2);
}
```